# In flutter_typehead TypeAheadField widget, how do I customize the message letting user know there is no matching item found?

Tags: flutter, dart, autocomplete, flutter-typeahead

I am trying to use this module https://github.com/AbdulRahmanAlHamali/flutter_typeahead to make a text field with autocomplete/"type ahead" functionality.

When the user searches an item in the text field form and the item is not found, there is a 'No Item Found' message returned. How do I customize this message for localization purposes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The **TypeAheadFormField** provides a callback which can be used to customize the message "No Item Found". I did not see this in the doc but its available. The callback is: **noItemsFoundBuilder** .

Here a sample code for using this callback:

```
TypeAheadFormField(
          textFieldConfiguration: TextFieldConfiguration(
              controller:
              decoration: 
              )),
          itemBuilder: (context, suggestion) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(''),
            );
          },
          noItemsFoundBuilder: (value) {
            var localizedMessage = "Parlez-vous Français!";
            return Text(localizedMessage);
          }, )
```

Comment: Hi @Keita, could you please tell me how I can show the suggestion box only after the user has typed at least 2 characters in the `TypeAheadField`: Here I've asked the question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77096136/typeaheadfield-how-to-show-the-dropdown-suggestion-box-only-after-2-characters.

Comment: @SaurabhJain can you try 'value'? Something like:   noItemsFoundBuilder: (value) {
    if (value && value.length > 2) {
      var localizedMessage = "Parlez-vous Français!";
      return Text(localizedMessage);
    }
  }

Comment: I see that you can also use "minCharsForSuggestions: 2," of course :)