# TypeAheadField: How to show the dropdown suggestion box only after 2 characters

Tags: flutter, autocomplete, typeahead

This is how I implemented the `TypeAheadField` which works fine and shows the dropdown suggestion box right after the user has clicked on the field.

```
TypeAheadField(
           noItemsFoundBuilder: (context) => const SizedBox(
           height: 50,
           child: Center(child: Text("No user found!")),
           ),
            suggestionsBoxDecoration: SuggestionsBoxDecoration(
            color: Colors.deepPurple.shade50,
           elevation: 4.0,
           borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                                  topLeft: Radius.circular(15),
                                  topRight: Radius.circular(15),
                                  bottomLeft: Radius.circular(15),
                                  bottomRight: Radius.circular(15))),
                          textFieldConfiguration: TextFieldConfiguration(
                            controller: _allLeaveViewModel.searchController,
                            onChanged: (value) {
                              setState(() {
                                _allLeaveViewModel.isSearchTextNotEmpty.value =
                                    value.isNotEmpty;
                              });
                              _allLeaveViewModel.updateList(value);
                              if (value.isEmpty) {
                                Utils.removeFocusFromSearch(context);
                              }
                            },
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                              contentPadding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                  16.0, 12.0, 16.0, 12.0),
                              hintText: 'Filter by applicant',
                              hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
                                  fontSize: 16),
                              filled: true,
                              border: OutlineInputBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(70),
                                borderSide: BorderSide.none,
                              ),
                              suffixIcon: Obx(() {
                                return Visibility(
                                  visible: _allLeaveViewModel
                                      .isSearchTextNotEmpty.value,
                                  child: IconButton(
                                    icon: Icon(
                                      Icons.cancel_outlined,
                                      color: Colors.grey.shade700,
                                      size: 25,
                                    ),
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      _allLeaveViewModel.clearSearchAndList();
                                    },
                                  ),
                                );
                              }),
                            ),
                          ),
                          suggestionsCallback: (String pattern) {
                            return _allLeaveViewModel.getSuggestions(pattern);
                          },
                          itemBuilder:
                              (BuildContext context, String suggestion) {
                            return Padding(
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
                              child: Row(
                                children: [
                                  const SizedBox(
                                    width: 10,
                                  ),
                                  Flexible(
                                      child: Text(
                                    suggestion,
                                    maxLines: 1,
                                    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                    style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                                  ))
                                ],
                              ),
                            );
                          },
                          onSuggestionSelected: (suggestion) {
                            setState(() {
                              _allLeaveViewModel.isSearchTextNotEmpty.value =
                                  suggestion.isNotEmpty;
                            });
                            _allLeaveViewModel.searchController.text =
                                suggestion;
                            _allLeaveViewModel.updateList(suggestion);
                          },
                        ),
```

But now what I want is to show the dropdown suggestion box only after the user has typed at least 2 characters in the `TypeAheadField`. can anyone please help me?

Comment: You should be using the built-in AutoComplete field now, not the typeahead package (badly named).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a property *minCharsForSuggestions* of the *ThypeAheadField* which you set to 2 and it would work as you want.

```
 TypeAheadField(
  minCharsForSuggestions: 2,
  //..
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

**First option:**

updating suggestionsCallback gives you in general more customization options as you have access to `String pattern`

```dart
TypeAheadField(
  // ... other properties ...

  suggestionsCallback: (String pattern) {
    // Check if the user has typed at least 2 characters
    if (pattern.length >= 2) {
      //Returns a Map<String, String>
      return _allLeaveViewModel.getSuggestions(pattern); //If returns 
    } else {
      // If not, return an empty Map to hide the suggestions
      return {};
    }
  },

  // ... other properties ...
   itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, Map<String,String> suggestion) {
    return ....                
   },
)
```

In the code above, we check the length of the `pattern` (the user's input) in the `suggestionsCallback`. If the length is greater than or equal to 2, we call `_allLeaveViewModel.getSuggestions(pattern)` to fetch the suggestions as before. If the length is less than 2, we return an empty list, effectively hiding the suggestions.

**Second option:**

using `minCharsForSuggestions: 2,`

Comment: Hi @DEFL, I have tried this many times when I apply the above condition in the `suggestionCallback`, I get this error: "The argument type 'Padding Function(BuildContext, String)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget Function(BuildContext, dynamic)'. "

Comment: I get this error in the `itemBuilder` which is right below the `suggestionCallback`, you can see the code in my question above.

Comment: I dont know what your getSuggestions... looks like but in case it returns a Map for example item builder needs to be modified to match that type    itemBuilder: (context, Map<String, String> suggestion) {}